# 24 bit recording in raspberry pi

Tags: raspbian, audio

I'm trying to record audio with 24 bit with 32k sample rate in raspberry pi. When I play the recorded file I'm getting glitches. I changed bit clock ratio to 48 (i.e., number of bits* number of channels(2)), and then it's recording ok.

But with this 48 bit clock ratio higher sample rate recording was not working.

Can any one help me in this? What's the relation between bit clock ratio and sample rate? Why that value different for higher sample rates and lower sample rates?

Comment: Would knowing the software and hardware being used be of any help in answering this question?

Comment: He is doing this on the, Pi... I dont think you will get more than 44.1kHz samples if that is what you want. I don't think it can play back more than that anyway I always had to to downsample and frankly surprised it works with more than 16bit samples...

Comment: "I dont think you will get more than 44.1kHz samples"...I didn't get this .you mean to say pi don't support less than 44.1kHz sample rates?